# How can I bundle a Mono / GTK# application on Linux?

Tags: linux, mono, gtk, gtk#, mkbundle

Here's the problem I'm running into: I wrote a Gtk# program using MonoDevelop and it runs great. But now I want to be able to run it on other Linux boxes without having to install MonoDevelop.

My solution has two projects: the main Gtk# application, and a C# library project upon which it depends. So when I build the main project, it makes MainProject.exe and MainProject.exe.mdb, along with DependencyProject.dll in the bin/Release folder.

I tried running the following command to package it all into a single executable (run from the bin/Release folder):

```
mkbundle MainProject.exe -o mainproject --deps *.dll
```

However, I get this error from running that command:

> Unhandled Exception:
>
> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'gtk-sharp'
>
> at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,bool)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.DefaultResolver (System.String refname, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.Load (System.String refname, IKVM.Reflection.Module requestingModule, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.Load (System.String refname) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 files, System.String codebase) [0x00000] in :0
>
> [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'gtk-sharp' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
>
> File name: 'gtk-sharp'
>
> at System.AppDomain.Load (System.String assemblyString, System.Security.Policy.Evidence assemblySecurity, Boolean refonly) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.AppDomain:Load (string,System.Security.Policy.Evidence,bool)
>
> at System.Reflection.Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad (System.String assemblyString) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.DefaultResolver (System.String refname, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.Load (System.String refname, IKVM.Reflection.Module requestingModule, Boolean throwOnError) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at IKVM.Reflection.Universe.Load (System.String refname) [0x00000] in :0
>
> at MakeBundle.QueueAssembly (System.Collections.Generic.List`1 files, System.String codebase) [0x00000] in :0

I saw a few other Stack Overflow questions with similar problems but none of them offered any practical solutions. How do I use this `mkbundle` command effectively?

Comment: I had same problem on a virtual machine ubuntu 14. When i moved to clean ubuntu 15 installation, mkbundle finished without any errors. Now i have different problem with built bundles, but will write about that in separate question.

Answer (score 1):

`mkbundle` is great if you want a completely stand-alone application, that does not rely on mono or anything related to mono to be installed in the target machine.

However, in the [mono pages](http://www.mono-project.com/archived/guiderunning_mono_applications/#bundles), you can read that:
"The resulting executable is self contained and does not need the Mono runtime installed to run. However, if your application relies on libraries linked to by the mono runtime or Gtk#, those will need to be installed (Gtk# helper libraries come to mind)."

If you just want to create a single executable from a few dll's, then [ILRepack](http://nugetmusthaves.com/Package/ILRepack) is a better choice.

If you are deploying to Windows, then you can just include the [GTK# installer](http://www.mono-project.com/download/#download-win) with your app (.NET is likely already present). If you are deploying to linux or mac, you need to have the **mono** packages (not necessarily `mono-complete`) installed before your app runs.

Hope this helps.

Comment: How can i bundle mono runtime with a GTK# App for Mac?Is it possible?

Comment: I don't really know. The Mac world is foreign for me.